# Difference between FactoryGirl.create and create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

Can you explain to me what is the difference to write in my tests :

```rb
FactoryGirl.create(:user, name: "boris", email: "boris@lehachoir.fr")
```

and

```rb
User.create(name: "boris", email: "boris@lehachoir.fr")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FactoryGirl` allows you to have some default (that can be overridden) values for `User` in the factory or even generate values using [Faker](https://github.com/stympy/faker) or similar.

That being said, for fast tests in most cases you can use `FactoryGirl.build_stubbed` (or `FactoryGirl.build`) which doesn't save user in database.

More info:
https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md